# Android Room: How to auto generate primary id, without using "autoGenerate = true" (To avoid SQLite keyword AUTOINCREMENT)?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

### Background

Just recently, I learn that using `AUTOINCREMENT` in SQLite is not encouraged.

https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

The keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` is in fact confusing. As, what it really mean is the algorithm method for generating id automatically.

Even if we do not use the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT`, and do not provide an `id` during insertion, the id will still be auto generated.

For instance,

```
DROP TABLE cities;

CREATE TABLE cities (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO cities (name)
VALUES( 'San Jose');

INSERT INTO cities (name)
VALUES( 'New York');
```

The following table will still be generated even without `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword

```
id  name
========
1   San Jose
2   New York
```

---

I want to achieve the same behavior in Android Room

Instead of using the following (which will apply SQLite `AUTOINCREMENT`)

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private long id;
```

I use in my entity class

```
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private long id;
```

However, I notice that I need to explicitly assign a non zero positive value to `id`, only the insertion will be success.

If the value for `id` is 0 or -1, then the insertion will not succeed

I expect we need not to assign id manually, even without using Room `autoGenerate = true`.

But, it seems like that doesn't work as expected. May I know why it is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expect we need not to assign id manually, even without using Room autoGenerate = true.

It is not necessary to use autogenerate = true, and have the same generation of values. You can use (another way is shown later):-

```
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private Long id; /* or private Long = null; */
```

Noting the use of the Long object rather than the long primitive. You then set id to null for a value to be generated or have suitable constructors.

Room sees the null, in the case of PRIMARY KEY and **a non-primitive** integer type, and omits the column from the generated SQL.

As an example based upon your schema consider :-

```
@Entity
class Cities {
   @PrimaryKey
   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @Ignore
   public Cities(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   @Ignore
   public Cities(Long id, String name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
   }
   public Cities(){}

   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

With a convenience @Insert e.g. :-

```
@Dao
interface CitiesDao {
    @Insert
    long insert(Cities city);
}
```

Alternately you could utilise an @Query to utilise an INSERT SQL that suits. e.g. the following will insert a row just given the name with a generated id. :-

```
@Query("INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES(:name)")
long insert(String name);
```

- The important factor is including the specific column(s) without the id column.

An example of using the above (2 methods) :-

```
    citiesdao.insert(new Cities("San Jose"));
    citiesdao.insert(new Cities("New York"));
    citiesdao.insert(new Cities(100L,"San Francisco"));
    citiesdao.insert(new Cities("Nevada"));
    citiesdao.insert("Dallas");
```

- you probably would not want to  use the third that inserts with a specific id (or could perhaps use `onConflict = IGNORE`).

The above results in (via App Inspection) :-

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the question. Using your example, that would imply that in Kotlin the id has to be a nullable Long, right?

Comment: @Xam Correct if `autoGenerate = false` is coded or if autoGenerate is omitted (implied false).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to achieve the same in Android room. In SQLite, a column with the type of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is an alias for the [ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), except if you specify `WITHOUT ROWID`.

So, upon insert your `id` will receive an unused integer unless specified otherwise.

The reason for not recommending the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword is that unless it's a `PRIMARY KEY`, then it is unlikely necessary to accept the costs in terms of CPU, memory usage, disk space and I/O overhead. However, using a `PRIMARY KEY` is in fact a good idea. Note that the page you have shared never claims you should not use a `PRIMARY KEY`, it just discourages the usage of the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword.